# Registry Key Value not Refreshing in C#

Tags: c#, registry

I've a registry key in:

```
HKLM\Software\bob\bob2
```

for example, named 'MyRegKey'.

I can read the value in fine in regedit, the command prompt (using 'reg query...'), and C# (see code below).

If I change the value in regedit, then re-run the command in command prompt, I get the updated value, yet if I rerun the C# code it still returns the old value. Even if I restart Visual Studio, the value remains the same.

Is there a way of 'refreshing' the registry in C# in some way? I'd rather not call 'reg query...' as a process from C#...

My code:

```
        const string MAIN_REGISTRY_KEY = @"SOFTWARE\bob\bob2";
        using (Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine)
        {
            using (var subkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(MAIN_REGISTRY_KEY))
            {
                var value = subkey.GetValue("MyRegKey");
                if (value == null)
                {
                    value = string.Empty;
                }
                this.MyKeyValue = (string)value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Right-click your EXE project, Properties, Build tab.  Untick the "Prefer 32-bit" option if you see it, change the Platform target setting to "AnyCPU".  You'll now no longer try to read SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\bob\bob2.

Comment: @HansPassant Why didn't you write this as an answer?

Comment: Because this has been answered many times before and I don't feel in the mood to find the duplicate.  Perhaps you can?

Comment: @HansPassant this worked great, thank you. Post as an answer?